# Literature on magnetism from the view of condensed matter physics

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, resource-recommendations, ferromagnetism

I am looking for a good book on magnetism.

It should be a condensed matter physics book, not focused on electromagnetism or electrodynamics.
The book should cover mechanisms/theories for explaining magnetism and different types of magnetic materials.
If possible, it should also include or focus on mathematical models used in theories of magnetism.

An example for a book I am looking for is
*J. Samuel Smart: Effective Field Theories of Magnetism (1966)*,
but this book is a bit old and therefore hard to aquire for me.

I know many condensed matter physics books which explain magnetism in several chapters but none of them is a single resource on magnetism.

Resources for (advanced) undergraduates are appreciated, but I am also happy with more advanced or more simple literature.

Comment: the one very often cited in phd theses on magnetism is by Siegmann&Stöhr

Comment: I liked Magnetism in Condensed Matter by Stephen Blundell

Comment: I really like Assa Auerbach's *Interacting Electrons and Quantum Magnetism*.